# I have multiple dvds to boot vista; can I somehow combine them to boot from single flash drive?

Tags: windows-vista, boot, usb-flash-drive, disc, hard-drive

My disk drive doesn't work.  I got an external one, but I can't boot from it apparently.  I can boot from USB, I've noticed.  So I'm wondering if I can put my 3 vista recovery discs onto a single bootable flash drive.  Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have 3 different DVDs you will probably need 3 different boot sectors. 
You will have to partition your usb drive into 3 partitions and then dump those dvds along with their boot sectors into them

> UPDATE
>   [Check this](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/combine-multiple-iso-images-burn-single-bootable-iso-image-file/)

Comment: No way to combine them huh?

Comment: There is way, I just found one. Updated my answer.